# SQL Server log file is too big

Tags: sql-server, logging

We are using SQL Server 2008 with full recovery model, the database size is 10 GB and the log file is 172 GB, we want to clear up the space of the log file internally ,we did transaction log file backup it should be clear up, but it still 172 GB ,what to do?

Answer (score 1):

> shrink the `DB` after doing the following `task` :
>
> /*Perform a full backup of your database.
>
> Change the backup method of your database to "Simple"
>
> Open a query window and enter "checkpoint" and execute
>
> Perform another backup of the database
>
> Perform a final full backup of the database.*/

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you need to understand the difference between file shrinkage and truncation.

Shrinking means physically shrinking the size of the file on disk. Truncation means logically freeing up space to be used by new data, but with NO impact on the size of the file on disk.

In layman's terms for instance, if your log file is 100 GB in size and you've never backed it up, 100GB of that size is USED. If you then back up the log / database, it will be truncated, meaning the 100GB will be reserved for future use... basically meaning it's freed up for SQL Server, but still uses up the same space on disk as before. You can actually see this with the following query for instance.

```
DBCC SQLPERF(logspace) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

The result will show on a DB basis how large the log file is, and how much of the log file is actually used. If you now shrink that file, it will free up the reserved portion of the file on disk.

This same logic applies to all files in SQL Server (including primary and partition files, as well as log files for tempdb, user databases etc), even on table-level. For instance if you run this code

```
sp_spaceused 'myTableName'
```

You will see how much of that table is reserved and used for various things, where the "unused" column will show how much is reserved but NOT used.

So as a conclusion, you can NOT free up space on disk without shrinking it. The real question here is why exactly are you not allowed to shrink the log? The typical reason for the recommendation to not shrink log files is because it will naturally grow to its normal size anyway, so there's no point. But if you're only stepping into the recommended practice of backing up the log anyway, it only makes sense to start by shrinking the oversized log first so that in the future your maintenance backups will keep it in its natural, comparatively smaller size.

Another **EXTREMELY IMPORTANT** point about shrinking, is that shrinking data files is another matter entirely. If you shrink a data file, you will be severely fragmenting all indexes and statistics on the database, making it mandatory to rebuild practically all the indexes on the entire database to avoid catastrophic degradation in performance. So do NOT shrink data files, ever, without consulting someone who knows what they're doing and is prepared to deal with the consequences. Log files are a lot safer in this regard since the fragmentation doesn't apply there.

Comment: i used the following query

Comment: and the result still 172 GB , that mean the T-log file still not freed up